# referencia a `operator delete[](void*)' sin definir

Tags: c++, compilar

He realizado el siguiente código y cuando intento compilarlo me salta el error "ocultar.cpp:(.text+0x5f): referencia a `operator delete' sin definir" me gustaría saber como solucionarlo.

Código (C++):

```
#pragma warning(disable: 4996)

#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>

class BMP
{
    char * data;                    // los pixeles del fichero

public:
    BMP();
    ~BMP();
    bool load(const char * fname);  // carga un fichero bmp
    void save(const char * fname);  // almacena el bmp en un fichero bmp
    int  ancho;
    int  alto;
    int  planosDeColor;
    int  bitsPorPixel;
    char * pixels;
    int  nPixels;
    long  fsize;
};

// obtener un entero a partir de un desplazamiento (offset) en un arreglo de caracteres
inline int getInt(char * data, int offset)
{
    return 0xff00000000&(int)(data[offset + 3] << 24) | 0xff0000&(int)(data[offset + 2] << 16) | 0xff00&(int)(data[offset + 1] << 8) | 0xff&(int)(data[offset + 0]);
}

// obtener un short (2 bytes) a partir de un desplazamiento (offset) en un arreglo de caracteres

inline int getShort(char * data, int offset)
{
    return 0xff00 & (int) (data[offset + 1] << 8) | 0xff & (int)(data[offset + 0]);
}

// metodo constructor de la clase
BMP::BMP()
{
    data = NULL;
    ancho = alto = 0;
}

// metodo destructor... liberar la memoria
BMP::~BMP()
{
    if (data)
        delete[] data;
}

// metodo para cargar un archivo
bool BMP::load(const char * fname)
{
    // primero abrimos el fichero para conocer su longitud
    FILE * f = fopen(fname, "rb");
    if (f == NULL)          // el archivo no existe
        return false;
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);  // ir al final del archivo
    fsize = ftell(f);       // en que posicion estamos?
    fclose(f);

    data = new char[fsize]; // reservar memoria para almacenar todo el contenido del fichero

    f = fopen(fname, "rb");
    fread(data, sizeof(char), fsize, f);
    fclose(f);

    int pixelsOffset = getInt(data, 10);
    int headerSize = getInt(data, 14);

    if (headerSize == 40) // BITMAPINFOHEADER
    {
        ancho = getInt(data, 18);
        alto  = getInt(data, 22);
        planosDeColor = getShort(data, 26);
        bitsPorPixel = getShort(data, 28);
        pixels = data + pixelsOffset;
    }

    nPixels = ancho * alto;

    return true;
}

// guarda el bitmap en un fichero
void BMP::save(const char * fname)
{
    if (data)
    {
        FILE * f = fopen(fname, "wb");
        fwrite(data, sizeof(char), fsize, f);
        fclose(f);
    }
}

// oculta el texto (str) en el mapa de bits
void ocultar(BMP & bmp, char * str)
{
    int pixelsRequeridos = (1 + strlen(str)) * 8; // calcula el numero de pixels requeridos para almacenar el string
    if (pixelsRequeridos <= bmp.nPixels) // el string cabe en los pixels del bmp
    {
        char * pixel;
        for (pixel = bmp.pixels; *str; str++)
        {
            // descomponer el siguiente caracter en sus bits
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++, *pixel++)
            {
                char bit = ((*str) >> i) & 1; // obtiene el siguiente bit
                if(bit)
                    *pixel |= 1;              // el bit es 1... ponerlo en el pixel actual
                else
                    *pixel &= 0xfe;           // el bit es 0... ponerlo en el pixel actual
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++, *pixel++)  // caracter de fin de string (\0) al final
            *pixel &= 0xfe;
    }
}

// obtiene un string escondido en un bmp y lo retorna en str
void mostrar(BMP & bmp, char * & str)
{
    char * pixel = bmp.pixels;

    // primero contamos cuantos caracteres hay en la imagen
    int n = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        char c = '\0';
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)  // obtener cada bit del caracter
        {
            char bit = ((*pixel) & 1) << i;
            c |= bit;   // concatenar el bit al caracter
            *pixel++;   // siguiente pixel
        }
        n++; // contar un caracter mas
        if (c == '\0') break;  // cuando lleguemos a \0 ya termino el string
    }

    // ahora repetimos el procedimiento anterior, pero esta vez construyendo el string (str)
    pixel = bmp.pixels;
    str = new char[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        str[i] = '\0';
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        {
            char bit = ((*pixel) & 1) << j;
            str[i] |= bit;
            *pixel++;
        }
    }
}

bool modoOcultar = false;
char * archivo1;
char * archivo2;

void imprimirUso(const char * programa)
{
    printf("Uso:\n%s archivo.bmp -ocultar archivo_oculto.bmp\n%s archivo.bmp -mostrar\n", programa, programa);
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    // primero debemos obtener los parametros de la linea de comandos
    if (argc == 4)  // 3 parametros
    {
        archivo1 = argv[1];  // el primer parametro es el nombre del bmp
        if (strcmp(argv[2], "-ocultar") == 0)  // el segundo parametro debe ser -ocultar
        {
            modoOcultar = true;
            archivo2 = argv[3];  // el tercer parametro es el nombre del bmp resultado
        }
        else
        {
            imprimirUso(argv[0]);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    else if (argc == 3)  // 2 parametros
    {
        archivo1 = argv[1];  // el primer parametro es el nombre del bmp
        if (strcmp(argv[2], "-mostrar") == 0)  // el segundo parametro debe ser -mostrar
        {
            modoOcultar = false;
        }
        else
        {
            imprimirUso(argv[0]);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        imprimirUso(argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    BMP bmp;
    if (!bmp.load(archivo1))  // intentar cargar el archivo
    {
        printf("Imposible abrir %s\n", archivo1);
        return 2;
    }

    if(modoOcultar)
    {
        // leer texto a ocultar:
        char texto[256];
        printf("Escriba el texto a ocultar: ");
        fgets(texto, 255, stdin);
        texto[strlen(texto) - 1] = '\0';  // quitar el caracter \n al final del string
        ocultar(bmp, texto);  // ocultar el texto en el mapa de bits
        bmp.save(archivo2);   // guardar el archivo resultante
    }
    else
    {
        char * buffer;

        mostrar(bmp, buffer);     // obtener el texto almacenado en el bmp
        printf("%s\n", buffer);   // e imprimirlo

        delete[] buffer;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: revisa el atributo pixels ya que cuando llega a la linea 121:  " char * pixel = bmp.pixels; " y se asigna a pixel no contiene nada de informacion.

Comment: A mí tu código no me da errores. Qué compilador estás usando?